# Can't find why NO_DATA_FOUND is being thrown

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to delete some registrations in a table using an external table (**tClean**), a cursor initialized with this tClean table, and a loop. The SELECT is supposed to find the id (**LabelId**) of the line corresponding to the cursor values in a view (**SetLabelListVW**) and put it into my variable **labelToDelete**. The DELETE after is supposed to delete the line with the id corresponding to labelToDelete in the table **SetLabel**.

The problem is that it raises a NO_DATA_FOUND exception for EVERY line fetched by the cursor. By the way, some lines that I'm supposed to delete do appear in my database, and others have been already deleted by simple SQL instruction.

Variable names, column names have been verified. I've tried a lot of differents things to find a solution and now I suspect lines :

```
WHERE "LabelCode" = lcode
AND "TypeLabelCode" = ltype
AND "LabelText" = ltext;
```

Maybe there is an error in this part of the code but I don't know what to do now.

This is the code :

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

DECLARE

labelToDelete       NUMBER(9);
labelUsed           EXCEPTION;
PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(labelUsed, -2292);
CURSOR  c IS SELECT * FROM tClean;
lcode   VARCHAR2(8);
ltype   VARCHAR2(8);
ltext   VARCHAR2(50);

BEGIN

OPEN c;
LOOP
    FETCH c INTO lcode, ltype, ltext;
    EXIT WHEN c%NOTFOUND;
    BEGIN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('lcode : ' || lcode);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ltype : ' || ltype);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ltext : ' || ltext);
        SELECT DISTINCT "LabelId" INTO labelToDelete
        FROM "SetLabelListVW"
        WHERE "LabelCode" = lcode
        AND "TypeLabelCode" = ltype
        AND "LabelText" = ltext;

        DELETE FROM "SetLabel"
        WHERE "SetLabelId" = labelToDelete;

        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Suppression du label Id : ' || labelToDelete || '  Label : ' || ltext);
        EXCEPTION

        WHEN labelUsed THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Exception ORA-2292 : le label ne peut être supprimé.');
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Exception ORA-01403 (NO_DATA_FOUND) : le label n''existe pas.' || ltext);
    END;
END LOOP;
CLOSE c;
--COMMIT;

 END;
```

And this is the result :

```
lcode : 00000195
ltype : MODSET
ltext : prout
Exception ORA-01403 (NO_DATA_FOUND) : le label n'existe pas.prout
lcode : 00000189
ltype : MODSET
ltext : pouet
Exception ORA-01403 (NO_DATA_FOUND) : le label n'existe pas.pouet
lcode : 00000169
ltype : MODSET
ltext : POUET POUET
Exception ORA-01403 (NO_DATA_FOUND) : le label n'existe pas.POUET POUET
lcode : 00000181
ltype : MODSET
ltext : pouet
Exception ORA-01403 (NO_DATA_FOUND) : le label n'existe pas.pouet
lcode : 00000182
ltype : MODSET
ltext : pouet
Exception ORA-01403 (NO_DATA_FOUND) : le label n'existe pas.pouet
lcode : 00000191
ltype : MODSET
ltext : pouet
Exception ORA-01403 (NO_DATA_FOUND) : le label n'existe pas.pouet
lcode : 00000183
ltype : MODSET
ltext : pouet 123
Exception ORA-01403 (NO_DATA_FOUND) : le label n'existe pas.pouet 123
lcode : CHARTEST
ltype : ACTPARAM
ltext : Caract�stique �ester
Exception ORA-01403 (NO_DATA_FOUND) : le label n'existe pas.Caract�stique     �ester
lcode : 00000022
ltype : MODSET
ltext : TEST bf
Exception ORA-01403 (NO_DATA_FOUND) : le label n'existe pas.TEST bf
lcode : 00000323
ltype : MODSET
ltext : test fp
Exception ORA-01403 (NO_DATA_FOUND) : le label n'existe pas.test fp
lcode : 00000008
ltype : MODSET
ltext : testghdgklh
Exception ORA-01403 (NO_DATA_FOUND) : le label n'existe pas.testghdgklh
lcode : CARAC
ltype : STEPCO
ltext : Caract�stique test
Exception ORA-01403 (NO_DATA_FOUND) : le label n'existe pas.Caract�stique test
lcode : TEST
ltype : CARACT
ltext : Dossier de test
Exception ORA-01403 (NO_DATA_FOUND) : le label n'existe pas.Dossier de test
```

Why am I getting that exception when the data does exist?

Edit : description of tClean, SetLabelListW, and creation request of tClean.

```
desc tClean;
Nom                                       NULL ?   Type
----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
LABELCODE                                          VARCHAR2(8)
TYPELABELCODE                                      VARCHAR2(8)
LABELTEXT                                          VARCHAR2(50)


desc "SetLabelListVW";
Nom                                       NULL ?   Type
----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
SetLabelLanguageId                        NOT NULL NUMBER(9)
LabelId                                            NUMBER(9)
TypeLabelId                                        NUMBER(9)
TypeLabelCode                                      VARCHAR2(8 CHAR)
SetLabelTypeId                            NOT NULL NUMBER(9)
CategoryLabelId                                    NUMBER(9)
OrdipatLabelCode                                   VARCHAR2(8 CHAR)
LabelCode                                          VARCHAR2(8 CHAR)
LabelText                                          VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)
CommentText                                        VARCHAR2(300 CHAR)
LongLabelText                                      VARCHAR2(100 CHAR)
SetLanguageId                             NOT NULL NUMBER(9)
SortNumber                                         NUMBER(5)
LanguageLabelCode                                  VARCHAR2(8 CHAR)
OrigineLanguageId                         NOT NULL NUMBER(9)
LastUpdateDate                                     DATE


CREATE TABLE tClean (
LabelCode VARCHAR2(8), 
 TypeLabelCode VARCHAR2(8), 
 LabelText VARCHAR2(50)
)
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
(
  TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
  DEFAULT DIRECTORY SYNCFILES
  ACCESS PARAMETERS
  (
    RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
    SKIP 1
    CHARACTERSET UTF8
    DNFS_ENABLE
    DNFS_READBUFFERS 10
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
    MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
    (
      LabelCode,
      TypeLabelCode,
      LabelText     
    )
  )
  LOCATION ('cleanLabel.csv')
)
PARALLEL 1
REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
```

I suspect an encoding problem.
My csv is UTF-8, my external table is UTF-8 and Oracle bdd is ALT32UTF8.
Or maybe, some access parameters in the external table request make a problem in the pl/sql code.
I don't know. I'm a little bit lost.

New edit :

It seems that following simple request works on SQL Developer but doesn't on SQL Plus.

```
SELECT DISTINCT "LabelId"
        FROM "SetLabelListVW"
        WHERE trim("LabelCode") = 'CHARTEST'
        AND trim("TypeLabelCode") = 'ACTPARAM'
        AND trim("LabelText") = 'Caractéristique à tester';
```

SQL Developer : LabelId = 100172209
SQL Plus : aucune ligne sÚlectionnÚe (encodage problem)

The whole code on the top of the question does'nt work neither on SQL Dev neither on SQL Plus.

Comment: It isn't the delete that's throwing the exception, it's the select; it's telling you there is no row in SetLabelListVW which matches 00000195/MODEST/prout. If you think that data does exist, can you add the table definitions? I suspect at least one table has `CHAR` columns instead of `VARCHAR2`, and the space padding is causing there to be no exact match.

Comment: Can you remove the "" from the table and column names ?  just to make sure you're referencing the actual columns, and not just using it as a static text in the query ?   after that, check if it's case sensitive.

Comment: @Amir - double quotes just make them quoted identifiers, which is necessary if they are mixed case. There would be a different error if those names were wrong, and if the quotes are removed.

Comment: @AlexPoole Yes this the SELECT ... INTO. Actually, lcode, ltype and ltext are referencing to VARCHAR2 columns in the view. I've already checked that :(

Comment: What type are they in tClean though? You can also dump the values from both tables, or display them concatenated with a fixed char to verify the length and check for stray whitespace.

Comment: @AlexPoole In tClean :

    Nom                                       NULL ?   Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 LABELCODE                                          VARCHAR2(8)
 TYPELABELCODE                                      VARCHAR2(8)
 LABELTEXT                                          VARCHAR2(50)

Comment: Please add the definition of both tClean and SetLabelListVW to the question, not as a comment. And maybe some data from both. Also `SELECT *` is suspicious, but it looks like you are fetching the right value into the right variable.

Comment: HAve you double-checked any of these values? For example, manually run the select for the first set: SELECT DISTINCT "LabelId"  FROM "SetLabelListVW" WHERE "LabelCode" = '00000195' AND "TypeLabelCode" = 'MODSET' AND "LabelText" = 'prout'. Is a field CHAR and not varchar so is padded with spaces?

Comment: Long shot - how is the external table delimited? Is it a DOS or UNIX line-ending format?

Comment: @TenG This is a DOS line-ending format. In the creation of the external table, I have "records delimited by newline".

Comment: @MichaelBroughton I have already tried to delete a single line. It works well.

Comment: @AlexPoole Description have been added to te question. Thank a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, datas in the last column of tClean (just on this column) had an hidden character at the end, even after trim function.
I was able to see this character != NULL only on sql Developper.

```
select substr(LabelText, 6, 1)
from tClean
where LabelText like '%prout%';
```

Result : "
"

```
select substr(LabelText, 7, 1)
from tClean
where LabelText like '%prout%';
```

Result : NULL

Answer (score 0):

It is for sure that it can't find the data in SetLabelListVW.

Try to use

```
SELECT DISTINCT "LabelId" INTO labelToDelete
FROM "SetLabelListVW"
WHERE trim("LabelCode") = trim(lcode)
AND trim("TypeLabelCode") = trim(ltype)
AND trim("LabelText") = trim(ltext);
```

This way, you can be sure that your table has the data and the problem might be the spaces in your tables.

Comment: I have added the function. The result is the same.

Comment: Could it be an encodage problem (between datas in my .csv file and datas in the db) ?